# Remove ''' from beginning and end of the strings in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

How we can remove `'''` from beginning and end of strings in a cell array in MATLAB R2015a? Suppose that we have this cell array:

[image]

When we open one of cells we have this:

[image]

I want convert whole cell array to double (numbers). Suppose that out cell array is `final`. Using `cellfun(@str2double,final)` returns `Nan` for all cells. `str2double(final)` returns `Nan` too.

**PS.**

10 last elements of `final` in command prompt has this structure:

```
 ans = 
    ''2310''
    ''2319''
    ''2313''
    ''2318''
    ''2301''
    ''2302''
    ''2303''
    ''2312''
    ''2304''
    ''2309''
```

Comment: @rayryeng . Your proposed duplicate answer didn't work here. Any suggestion or hint?

Comment: **Why** does it not work?  Update your post with your attempt and show us what went wrong.  We aren't mindreaders.  It would also be fruitful if you could post your data somewhere for us to take a look.

Comment: If you are getting `NaN`, then your cell array is not what you say it is.  Please show us what the output looks like when you do `final(1:20)` for example in the MATLAB command prompt.  Do **not** give us a screenshot of your workspace.

Comment: Thank you. post updated.

Comment: Reopened and I've placed an answer.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace all of the apostrophe characters with nothing, then apply [`str2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) to each cell in your cell array.

Given that your cell is stored in `final`, do something like this:

```
final_rep = strrep(final, '''', '');
out = cellfun(@str2double, final_rep);
```

Basically, use [`strrep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) to replace all of the apostrophe characters with nothing, then apply `str2double` to each cell in your cell array via [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html).

Given your example above:

```
final = {'''2310'''
'''2319'''
'''2313'''
'''2318'''
'''2301'''
'''2302'''
'''2303'''
'''2312'''
'''2304'''
'''2309'''};
```

We now get this:

```
>> out =

        2310
        2319
        2313
        2318
        2301
        2302
        2303
        2312
        2304
        2309

>> class(out)

ans =

double
```

As you can see, the output of the array is `double`, as we expect.